# Return characters before first space in a string using conditional count of alphabets

Tags: r

i have a df , consider

```
ID     Name
1     Jon Wick
2     Ronny
3     Misha Mansoor
4     Ed Hermids
5     Ro Misha
```

I want to process this in two ways

- If a name contains less than 3 alphabets in the First Name before first space in the name string then return the full name .
- If it contains greater than 3 alphabets in the first name before first space then return only First Name .

leave one word names as it is .

Also need to store this in a data frame .

Results should be as

```
ID     Name
1     Jon
2     Ronny
3     Misha
4     Ed Hermids
5     Ro Misha
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` by matching words with characters more than 2  (`\\w{3,}`), capture it as a group (by wrapping it with `()`), followed by one more more white space (`\\s+`) followed by one more more non-white space characters (`\\S+`).  In the replacement, we use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured string.  This will make sure that it will only match those words with more than 2 characters and leave all those strings as such.

```
sub("(\\w{3,})\\s+\\S+", "\\1", df1$Name)
#[1] "Jon"        "Ronny"      "Misha"      "Ed Hermids" "Ro Misha"
```

Comment: @PankajKaundal  Yes, I will add the description